# Copy paste file from an Ubuntu directory to Windows directory using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, wsl-2

Like the title of the question says i am wondering why i get following error when executing following command inside my bash script:

Command:
`sudo cp openssl/localhost.pfx /mnt/c/Users/bob/.aspnet/https`

Output:
`cp: cannot create regular file '/mnt/c/Users/bob/.aspnet/https': No such file or directory`

The directory on Windows does exists!

Comment: why do you use `**` for Users?

Comment: Its just to hide the path :)

Comment: I don't understand. are you really typing ** ? if you are hiding the real user name, change it to example, or bob or john, eg. '/mnt/c/Users/bob/.aspnet/https'

Comment: There you go, i changed it

Comment: is "https" a folder, or you want the target file to have the name "https" ?

Comment: Are you sure this path exists? can you cd to it?

Comment: https is a folder yes. from this folder i want to copy the localhost.pfx file from this linux dir to windows

Answer (score 1):

If your path is correct, you can try running this command after sudo su:

```
sudo su
cp openssl/localhost.pfx /mnt/c/Users/bob/.aspnet/https
```

Comment: If the command didn't work directly with sudo, it won't work either after a sudo su. Something else is going on.

Comment: @joanis that isn't true sudoers group has different permissions than root typicall. https://superuser.com/questions/299322/what-is-different-between-root-and-sudo

Comment: The weird thing about it is that following command works: `sudo cp openssl/localhost.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates` but the one that i mention in the question don't. Both paths exists (can cd to both paths in a manual way)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with mounting?

Comment: @MaximilianBallard you're t right, I wasn't thinking straight. Thanks for the correction.